# How could I stop UIScrollView from bouncing if there's no scroll distance?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollView which I want to bounce when it scrolls, but currently it's able to bounce despite the content size being the same as the frame. How can I stop it from bouncing if the content size and frame are the same size? Is there a more elegant way than overriding setContentSize and setFrame with a check for it?

Answer (score 1):

You can have check that

```
    if(scrollView.contentSize==frame.size)

    {

       scrollView.bounce = NO;

    }

    else

    {

      scrollView.bounce = YES;

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use KVO to listen for changes to the content size.